# R factor cast as a numeric when used as a list index/key

Tags: r

In the example I've shown below, why is the factor treated as a numeric and not a character or factor?

```
myList <- list()
myList[["hello"]] <- 1
myList[["world"]] <- 2
myList[[factor("world")]] <- 3
```

outputs:

```
$hello
[1] 3

$world
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a factor has two interpretations, one as a numeric and one as a character. When a factor is used to index a list the numeric version is the default. See a good blog post [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/indexing-with-factors/) as well as many more such fun R eccentricities in "The R Inferno" [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.burns-stat.com%2Fpages%2FTutor%2FR_inferno.pdf&ei=oluEVfroKMfYoASKvaewAQ&usg=AFQjCNFxw7msY4kAkwvv07FkiU57EpNTLw&sig2=nzFQLivDZ2bLv7SfMuglVg&bvm=bv.96339352,d.cGU).